# Can i use firebase cloud messaging without notification permission ? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I only need fcm for sharing data and not for notification. Is it mandatory to ask for notification permission for that?

Comment: What do you mean by "sharing data"?

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes I mean sending some text from one client to another

Answer (score 3):

I realize no one is likely to see this answer, but I came across this while researching... thought I'd include the answer for future viewers.

Yes, it is mandatory to ask for permission, even if you don't intend to show the user a notification. There's been a recent question here asking the same basic question: [Can i use firebase cloud messaging without notification permission? (Javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53403792/can-i-use-firebase-cloud-messaging-without-notification-permission-javascript) that has a couple good answers explaining why by people way smarter and more experienced than me.

In case anyone can't access that question in the future, I'll include Google Dev Adocate [Doug Stevenson's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/807126/doug-stevenson) excellent concise explanation here:

> It's to protect the user's preferences about what your app is allowed
>   to do. The way push messaging works on browsers is by using a service
>   worker. Even though you say you don't need a service worker, you are
>   actually making using of it when using Firebase Cloud Messaging in
>   your app.
>
> Given that, the prompt is necessary because the browser doesn't know
>   what you intend to do with that push message. If the user doesn't
>   trust your app, they should have the right to limit what it can
>   actually do, especially when they're not using your app. Mobile
>   operating systems (iOS, Android) are the same way.

Comment: I saw it! Thanks.